# Can I register multiple resources with one handler and one URI in Open Rasta?

Tags: c#, rest, openrasta

I want to register mutliple resources with one handler and one URI.so want to confirm that is this possible in open rasta.
I have gone through a bit of websites regarding open rasta but couldn't able to conclude that whether this is possible or not?

```
  ResourceSpace.Has
           .ResourcesOfType<Request>()
           .AtUri("/processing")
           .HandledBy<SomeHandler>()
           .TranscodedBy<SomeCodec>();
```

I need to handle all the request which are derived from the base class "Request".
It would be great if some body could actually shed light on this.

Comment: Haven't tried if the OpenRasta framework enforces this but having one URI registered for multiple resources is certainly a violation of the REST architectural style. A resource can have many URIs (addresses) but a URI should only **address** a single resource.

Comment: @SixtoSaez: I understand your point but don't you think it is just a view how you see your resource.Here I have a point of view that all are of type "Request".So i am not seeing them as different resources.

Comment: If you want to represent different "view" of a resource then what you want to use is a different codec in OpenRasta. In REST different media types (codec) can be used to represent a given resource but an address should only identify a specific resource.

Answer (score 2):

So if everything *is* a request and you want to tunnel stuff, you can, using the registration you have provided.

The matching will be done based on the most approaching type, so

```
public void Post(SpecificRequest specificRequest) { /*handles the SpecificRequest type */ }
public void Post(Request myRequest) { /* handles the default case */ }
```

That said, be aware that in ReSTful system we tend to try and identify different *things* with different URIs, leading to one registration per type.

Answer (score 2):

In my fairly limited experience of OpenRasta you can use the .And method to add additional .AtUri resource locations.

I.e. in your case

```
ResourceSpace.Has
       .ResourcesOfType<Request>()
       .AtUri("/processing").And.AtUri("/processing/{processid}")
       .HandledBy<SomeHandler>()
       .TranscodedBy<SomeCodec>();
```

where the {curley brackets} specify the input parameter of your Handler method i.e.:

```
public class SomeHandler
{
    public Request Get(int processid = 0) //specify a default value for the uri case /processed
    {
        if (processid == 0)
            return Context.Set<Request>().ToList(); //Context comes from my DbContext derived class which is part of my entity model.
        else
            return GetRequestFromProcessId(processid) //this is a private method in your handler class using Linq to SQL to retreive the data your interested in.  I can't see your handler so I'm making it up.
     }
 }
```

I found in the OpenRasta documentation a note which specifed that you MUST have destinct (only one) ResourceSpace definition for each matching Type and Handler.  In other words you must not duplicate the same ResourceOfType class with the same HandledBy handler class.  I tested this and it is the case and perhaps why you are asking the question in the first place.

N.b. this code is completely untested, I've just taken the patern of what I've written and substituted in your classes and uri where known.  This also assumes you are trying to retrieve data from a HTTP GET verb.  The other contributer, went down the POST route, but you haven't specified.